# Java's equalsIgnoreCase fails with ß ("Sharp S" used in German alphabet)

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, locale

my first question here :-)
Did my best reading the rules and searching if the question was already asked before.

The following code

```
    String[] strings = {"cAsE", "\u00df"};
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.println(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str.toLowerCase()));
        System.out.println(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str.toUpperCase()));
    }
```

outputs true 3 times (cAsE = case; cAsE = CASE; ß = ß)
but also 1 false (ß != SS).
Tried using toLowerCase(Locale) but it did't help.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Michael Kaplan has written extensively about the German Sharp S character. Things have changed recently and I'd expect libraries to be playing some catch-up. Lots of good information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2008/05/15/8506679.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until recently, Unicode didn't define an uppercase version of s-sharp. I'm not sure whether the latest Java 7 version does already include this new character and whether it handles it correctly. I suggest to give it a try.

The reason why `str.toLowerCase()` doesn't return the same as `str.toUpperCase().toLowerCase()` is that Java replaces `ß` with `SS` but there is no way to go back, so `SS` becomes `ss` and the compare fails.

So if you need to level the case, you must use `str.toLowerCase()`. If not, then simply calling `equalsIgnoreCase()` without any upper/lower conversion should work, too.

Comment: Even if Java 7 supports the new Unicode character, "ß".toUpperCase() must still return "SS", since the upper-case "ß" is only of typographical interest and not really used in the wild: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ß

Comment: In my case I'm trying to match some users' strings with predefined ones (maybe I should have mentioned it in the original question...)
So the code I gave here as an example is just a test I performed to understand why my original code didn't work as expected.
Obviously the equalsIgnoreCase method exists to save us from changing the case of either strings.

Anyway, the concept of "leveling" is what makes this my accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Aaron Digulla has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334004/javas-equalsignorecase-fails-with-sssharp-s-used-in-german-alphabet/1334049#1334049). Also, it isn't meaningful to transform the string in the absence of locale data. In English, the upper case of **i** is **I**, but in Turkish it is **İ**. [String.compareIgnoreCase](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) does not take locale data into account.

(As an aside, you might want to look into [normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html), or you'll end up wondering why **"é".equals("é")** can return false. *Reason: one is a [combining sequence](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_javadatatypes)*.)

Comment: it is weird to me that the String class has 2 methods each for toLowerCase & toUpperCase
(one without parameters + one that accepts a Locale)
but only 1 method each for equalsIgnoreCase & compareToIgnoreCase

if the guys at Sun think the *case methods should be Locale sensitive then I expect all of them to also accept it.

Thanks for the normalization link, it's an overkill for my case, but   insightful all the same.

Comment: @targumon: Note that in *all* locales `"ß".toUpperCase(locale)` returns `"SS"`, yet equalsIgnoreCase doesn't care. It's all broken somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> Unicode didn't define an uppercase version of s-sharp
>   this is the exact point - in the german language there is no possibility of an sharp-s (ß) being a capital or the initial letter of any word. therefore its just non-sense arguing about a capital ß...

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I don't know anything about the German language, but I'm not sure how I feel about Unicode characters being treated as equivalent to some Roman-letter expansion. Should you be able to do the following?

```
myDictionary.put("glasses", new Bifocals());
myDictionary.get("glaßes");
```

If you have your druthers, `myDictionary.get("glaßes")` should return something the `Bifocals` from before. Is that legit?

Comment: "ß" and "ss" is not equivalent. "ss" is sometimes used to write "ß" when that letter is not available. Since there is no upper-case "ß" (ok, there is one, but it's mostly a typographical curiosity and not a letter that's used in reality) it will always be written as "SS" in ALL CAPS. The opposite is not true: "SS".toLower() is definitely "ss".